# Multiple Post Repeat for Related Post Loop by Category

Tags: posts, categories, loop

This is my code:

```
if ( is_single() ) {
    $categories = get_the_category();
    if ( $categories ) {
        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
            $cat      = $category->cat_ID;
            $args     = array(
                'post_type'  => 'locali',
                'cat'        => $cat,
                'post__not_in' => array( get_queried_object_id() ),
                'order'      => 'DESC',
                'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'key'     => '_wti_total_count',
                        'value'   => '',
                        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'     => '_wti_total_count',
                        'value'   => '',
                        'compare' => 'NOT IN'
                    )
                )
            );
            $count    = 0;
            $my_query = null;
            $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

                while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php $count ++; ?>
                    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" class="anchor-mask"></a>
                        <header>
                            <div class="cat-icon-wrapper">
                                <div class="cat-icon">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <div class="icon-marker">
                                            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/marker-white.png">
                                            <p class="num"><?php echo $count; ?></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="entry-header">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <?php the_title( "<h4>", "</h4>" ); ?>
                                </a>

                                <div class="address">
                                    <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_indirizzo', true ); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </header>
                        <!-- .entry-header -->
                        <footer>
                            <div class="rating-wrapper">
                                <span>
                                    <?php
                                    $Like   = abs( GetWtiLikeCount( $post->ID ) );
                                    $Unlike = abs( GetWtiUnLikeCount( $post->ID ) );

                                    $totalLike   = $Like * 10;
                                    $totalUnlike = $Unlike * 0;

                                    $Sum   = $totalLike + $totalUnlike;
                                    $Count = $Like + $Unlike;

                                    $averange = $Sum / $Count;

                                    echo round( $averange, 2 );

                                    ?>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="entry-footer">
                                <?php comments_number( 'nessuna recensione', '1 recensione', '% recensioni' ); ?>
                            </div>
                        </footer>
                        <!-- .entry-summary -->
                    </article><!-- #post-## -->
                <?php
                endwhile;
            }
        }
    }
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

This is an example:
[image]

Comment: what's your question exactly?

Comment: I need to show the post with the same categories of the post that you are viewing, I changed the query to create the loop, but it duplicates some items I would like to show me only once the post associated with the spread category, I hope I was clear, thanks for the help